# hibernate Join with criteria with distinct won't work

Tags: java, hibernate

when i run i got resulted query where i expect Actual Query

Actual Query(to be Produce, Desire Query)
distinct [ID]

```
select distinct rc.* from ratecodeparam rcp , ratecodes rc where rc.travelfrom <= '2011-04-22' and rc.travelto >= '2011-04-25' and rc.id = rcp.p_id;
```

OR

```
select distinct rc.* from ratecodeparam rcp join ratecodes rc on rc.travelfrom <= '2011-04-22' and rc.travelto >= '2011-04-25' and rc.id = rcp.p_id;
```

**I want**

> distinct rc.*

Code

i got through code but disticnt rc.*

```
  session.createCriteria(RateCode.class)
            .add(Restrictions.le("travelFrom", from.getTime()))
            .createCriteria("rateCodeParams", "rcp")
    list = crit.list();
```

RateCode.hbm.xml

```
<class catalog="hermes" name="com.RateCode"  table="ratecodes">
        <id name="rateCodeId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id"/>
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="code" type="string">
            <column length="32" name="code" unique="true"/>
        </property>
        <set name="rateCodeParams" cascade="all, delete-orphan" order-by="param">
            <key>
                <column name="p_id"  />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.RateCodeParam" />
         </set>
</class>
```

RateCodeParam.hbm.xml

```
<class catalog="hermes" name="com.RateCodeParam" table="ratecodeparam">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id"/>
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>       
        <many-to-one  class="com.RateCode" name="rateCode" insert="false" fetch="join" update="false" > 
            <column name="p_id" />
        </many-to-one>
</class>
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: my question is when i run i got resulted query where i expect Actual Query

Comment: Please edit your posting and put your question there (not just in a remark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is missing a join because you don't add one to the query. Setting the fetch mode (*setFetchMode*) just adds more details to an existing join. But in your query it doesn't exist.

The correct query probably looks like this:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(RateCode.class)
    .add(Restrictions.le("travelFrom", from.getTime()))
    .createCriteria("rateCodeParams", "rcp");
list = crit.list();
```

Comment: thanx i got same code through google here but (select distinct rc.* )

Comment: for distinct rc.* 
crit.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("rc.*"))) but how to give alias to RateCode.class

Comment: Alias for RateCode: Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(RateCode.class, "rc");